# Attaching two network cards two different drivers

Tags: kernel-modules, drivers, networkcard

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server that has two 10 Gb ethernet cards that are using the `ixgbe` driver. I'm installing the [PF_RING DNA](http://www.ntop.org/products/pf_ring/) drivers for these cards (what that is isn't important). I want interface `eth0` to use the original Linux `ixgbe` driver and I want interface `eth1` to use the new PF_RING `ixgbe` driver.

The first issue is that both drivers have the same name. I need to load both of them with `insmod ixgbe.ko`, but I can't since they have the same name. Can I load one of them under a different name, like `ixgbe-dna`? I can recompile the kernel modules if that's the only option.

Once I have two drivers `ixgbe` and `ixgbe-dna` loaded, how can I specify that `eth0` will use `ixgbe` and `eth1` will use `ixgbe-dna`?

Answer (score 3):

Loade driver with different name:
modprobe [modulename] -o [newname]

Replace the driver of the networkinterface:  get the device ID e.g. lspci -nn.

Unbind the driver:
`echo -n "[THE_ID]" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/[OLD_DRIVER]/unbind`

And rebind it to the driver you wish:
`echo -n "[THE_ID]"> /sys/bus/pci/drivers/[NEW_DRIVER]/bind`

Comment: I don't think my version of modprobe supports the -o flag. When I run `modprobe --version` I get `module-init-tools version 3.16`. I'll try building the latest version from source and see if it works.

Comment: Even the version in the new Ubuntu package kmod doesn't have the `-o` flag. On which version of modprobe does that work for you?

Comment: Wrote it down some time ago... The feature got disabled 2010 :-/